# Sonarqube 5.1.2 not showing technical dept

Tags: sonarqube, technical-debt

We are using sonarqube version 5.1.2 for our java and scala projects.Earlier sonarqube used to show technical depts and that can be seen in the time machine but as of now it is not showing technical dept for any of the project.What may be the possible reasons behind this so that I can get a rough idea about it and start working on that point to resolve this issue.We have not migrated from any versions recently.

Comment: 6.4 is the current version and 5.6.6 is the current LTS version. You're going to have a hard time finding support for versions prior to that. You should seriously consider upgrading.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ann...We were planning to upgrade it anyway...Now will have to do it on priority basis...